# how to parse time from time function with bash and grep?

Tags: bash

I have this bit of info from a bash script.
How can I keep only the time?

```
"real\t0m0.001s"
```

Needs to be

```
0m0.001s
```

or even count of milliseconds.. The output is produced from
`time` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` with a simple regular expression that replaces from the start of the string through the `'\t'` (tab) character with nothing (removing that part of the string), e.g.

```
sed 's/^.*\t//'
```

Using `grep` you would use:

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]*$'
```

(to only match non-space characters to end of string)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "real\t0m0.001s" | sed 's/^.*\t//'
0m0.001s
```

or

```
$ printf "real\t0m0.001s" | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*$'
0m0.001s
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about ms count? like converting this "0m1.999s" to 1000ms

Comment: Wouldn't that be a round to `2000ms`? If so, then I would use `awk` which handles floating point numbers. `grep` and `sed` process characters (or digits), but have no concept of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is meant for exactly this:

```
$ printf 'real\t0m0.001s' | cut --fields=2
0m0.001s
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps :
`grep -o '.\{8\}$' test.txt`